# Android TV and TV boxes which display refresh rate support for live video play,

Tags: android, android-tv

when playing a video the video can have different FPS , usually 24/25 for live streams and 30 for on demand videos, some android devices like TV and TV boxes supports different display refresh rate, what I need is to get video FPS of the currently playing video and set the display refresh rate according to it, let's say 1080p50hz for live and 1080p60hz for ondemand videos (if the device supports it of course)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `android.media.tv` libraries you can get the refresh rate of the currently playing content from [TvTrackInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvTrackInfo.html#getVideoFrameRate()). Based on that you can set the preferred display mode of your display in your Window's `mWindowAttributes`. You can check what modes your display supports with `Display.getSupportedModes()`.